# Preview of math formulars in ASCiiDoc (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio, asciidoc

I am using VS Code to write a document in ASCiiDoc. Part of this document are math formulas.

My problem is that preview of this formulars does not work.  For example: If I write

```
latexmath:[\alpha(t_i)]
```

the preview is

(\alpha(t_i)).

In Git intepretation of this works, but not locally in preview. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was discussed in the following GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode/issues/165
- https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode/issues/279

The solution appears to be to change the `Asciidoc: Change Preview Security Settings` to `Disable` to allow the remote content for the images to load.